# How can i add attribute to TD using this code

Tags: jquery

I want to add attribute to my td element. But i cant make it work.

Here's the code i used. I hope you can help me. Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#table_1 tr td").each(function(){

        //console.log($(this).attr("class"));

        if ($(this).hasClass('column-escalationnotes')){
            $(this).attr("id", "1");
            console.log('hey');
        }


    });
```

here's the code of the table. I removed some part:

```
    <table id="table_1" class="scroll  display nowrap data-t data-t wpDataTable dataTable no-footer" style="" data-described-by="table_1_desc" data-wpdatatable_id="52" role="grid" aria-describedby="table_1_info">
....
<!-- Table body -->      
<tbody>
<tr role="row" class="odd"><td class="  column-escalationnotes">CASE CLOSE SHIP ALREADY</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

My plan is to add OnMouseOver attribute to that TD with classname "column-escalationnotes". I tried to select that TD and use .hover() but i i cant make it also. That's why i just want to add OnMouseOver attribute.

Comment: can you provide HTML sample for the `table` ? Note that this code will result invalid html (duplicated ids)

Comment: Added. Those id values are for testing purpose only if the code will work.

Comment: I tried your code and it's working. You forgot to close the function `$(document).ready(function(){` in the provided code, but I think it is a bad copy paste

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works, you just forgot to close the first function.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#table_1 tr td").each(function() {

    //console.log($(this).attr("class"));

    if ($(this).hasClass('column-escalationnotes')) {
      $(this).attr("id", "1");
      console.log('hey');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-pasqAKBDmFT4eHoN2ndd6lN370kFiGUFyTiUHWhU7k8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<table id="table_1" class="scroll  display nowrap data-t data-t wpDataTable dataTable no-footer" style="" data-described-by="table_1_desc" data-wpdatatable_id="52" role="grid" aria-describedby="table_1_info">
  ....
  <!-- Table body -->
  <tbody>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td class="  column-escalationnotes">CASE CLOSE SHIP ALREADY</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```